# Execute nodejs on azure vm (windows server 2012)?

Tags: node.js, azure, windows-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

I'm created chat with nodejs in visual studio and it's working well on my localhost but my website on azure, so i created virtual machine (windows server 2012).(Note : it is not a classic virtual machine)
and installed necessary software NodeJS.and copy my nodejsapp folder into virtual machine.

Snippet code here (server.js)...

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    server: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxx',

    options: {
        encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
    }
}
console.log(config); 


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

   socket.on('join room', function (data) {console.log('joined-->'+data.email);
        socket.join(data.email); 
    });

   socket.on('leave room', function (data) {console.log('Leaved-->'+data.email);
        socket.leave(data.email); 
    });

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
            console.log('sent==>'+data.id+"  , "+data.to+'  ,  '+data.from+'  ,  '+data.msg  );
            io.sockets.in(data.to).emit('chat message', {id: data.id, to:data.to,from: data.from, msg: data.msg });

    });    

});

http.listen(5556, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:5556');
});
```

after that using command prompt try to run server.js but not run node.

[image]

it's working on local machine but not in vm.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that another program has node.exe in the environment path. In your case it's probably Microsoft HPC Pack. 
Type echo %PATH% and see if (C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2\Bin) comes before of your node.js folder (C:\Program Files\nodejs). if so, change the Path so the node.js path will be before the HPC path.

Comment: Actually I am new to azure and azure vm.As per your suggestion,I  just uninstall nodejs from c drive and install again nodejs on D drive. and my node project folder also in  D drive.again try to run  but still problem is not solve.

Comment: @MohitSolanki  Did u change the path in the environment path like I suggested? reinstalling won't help you because when you execute node.exe it will go first to the Microsoft HPC pack

Comment: how to change the path? plz help me to find out.

Comment: https://lsdbtech.wordpress.com/2015/05/28/windows-server-2012-r2-change-environment-variables/

Comment: Hi @shachar I just changed path C:\Users\dea\AppData\Roaming\npm to  D:\node-setup and try to run but still problem not solve.

Comment: @MohitSolanki ,  You need to make sure that the path of the HPC Pack (C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2\Bin) is not before the path you have added.

Comment: I checked, there is no any path before newly added. but still not solve.

Comment: Hi @shachar I dont know but after that all i had restart my VM and try to run my nodejs app and it's working. tx bro. 
I marked the answer correct. The provided answer was extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used an HPC Pack compute node template to create the VM instance and build up your application.

[image]

By defaule, the `node` is the alias name for `HPC` commands in this template. And it doesn't have a node.js environment if you don't munaully install one. Actually, you can use the absolute path of the node.js execution application.

Also, you can use a normal version of VM template such as
[image]

Install node.js and make sure to configure the path of nodejs folder in system `PATH`. Otherwise, you can simply package the node.js execution application's folder in your project's directory and deploy them to Azure VM togather. Then use the absolute path of the node.js execution to run your node.js server.

## update

You can select those VM template without HPC pack, when you add a new resource in marketplace.
[image]

Comment: HI @Gary Liu - MSFT. I am new to azure and azure vm.As per your suggestion,I  just uninstall nodejs from c drive and install again nodejs on D drive. and my node project folder also in  D drive.again try to run  but still problem is not solve.

Comment: Have you changed to use the common VM template without the HPC Pack?

Comment: still i dont use. how to use VM template because before said and again repeating, i'm new to AZURE . plz help me to find out.

Comment: Hi @Gary Liu - MSFT thanx for replay and guidance.
thank you bro.